# Needs clarification regarding the operator "+ ="

Tags: python, list

I know if I do

```
x = 1
```

and then

```
x += 1
```

the result is

```
x=2
```

And equally

```
x = x + 1
```

the result is also

```
x = 2
```

so why when iterating over a list is not the same?

For example:

```
lst = [[1,3,3],[2,2,2],[3,2]]
for i in lst:
  if len(i)!=3:
    i = i +  [0]*1

print(lst)
```

The result is:

```
[[1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2]]
```

And if we use this code:

```
lst = [[1,3,3],[2,2,2],[3,2]]
for i in lst:
  if len(i)!=3:
    i +=  [0]*1

print(lst)
```

the result is:

```
[[1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: I think you copy/pasted the same code twice

Comment: `a = a + b` and `a += b` are simply not the same. `+` and `+=` are entirely independent operators, that any type can implement as they please with the appropriate dunder methods. For most built-in mutable types, `a += b` is a mutation on `a`.